# What's the most efficient way to use MPI RDMA in read-only?

Tags: c++, mpi, rdma

I'm currently dealing with a situation which should be really fast to handle with MPI one-sided communications, but I'm struggling to find similar examples and I'm not sure to have made the optimal choices.

Each MPI process owns a very large vector, and needs to access data from other processes' vectors in an unpredictable scheme, that means I can't know in advance the frequency and the sizes of the messages, nor the exact moment these data will be needed. The huge advantage I have is that these vector will stay constant during the entire function call where these communication will happen, so I don't have to care about synchronization between read and write instructions.

So to be more precise, I need for each process :

1. An initial synchronization with all other processes to create a Window on the vector
2. Alternating between remote reads on all other processes and data processing, as many times as needed
3. A final synchronization with all other processes to close the window

At the moment I went for this code structure :

```
//Initial sync
MPI_Win window;
MPI_Win_create(..., &window);
MPI_Win_fence(0, window);

//reading and processing data
MPI_Win_lock_all(MPI_MODE_NOCHECK, window);

while (keep_on)
{
    //loop over every process excepted world_rank
    for (int offset = 1; offset < world_size; ++offset)
    {
        int target = (world_rank + offset)%world_size;
        MPI_Get(..., window);
    }

    MPI_Win_flush_local_all(window);
    //process data and update keep_on
    [...]
}

MPI_Win_unlock_all(window)

//final sync
MPI_Win_fence(0, window);
MPI_Win_free(&window);
```

And now I have some remarks/questions :

1. I used lock and unlock function only because they are needed to call flush, but I don't really see the point of these calls, so is there a better approach?
2. I tried to use MPI_Rget/MPI_Wait instead of lock-get-flush-unlock but couldn't figure how to make it work, maybe some additional function calls are needed. I got this error :

```
An error occurred in MPI_Rget
reported by process [4181227537,28]
on win ucx window 3
MPI_ERR_RMA_SYNC: error executing rma sync
```

3. Is the MPI_MODE_NOCHECK useful here? I'm a bit confused not to precise anywhere an MPI_NO_PUT as it would allow MPI to understand that I want a read-only access to the window.

Thank you for reading this post

Comment: If it's read-only, consider MPI shared memory. That means only one process per node stores your data.

Comment: Unless you are memory constrained, why don't you simply broadcast the vector?

Comment: Fencing is for active targets. and lock is for passive ones. Not sure what happens under the hood if you mix both. Give passive only RMA a try.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout This vector actually stores a tree structure, it's a vector of tree nodes pointing either to two other tree nodes or to a leaf object. These trees are heavy to build and update, and are therefore intentionally distributed one per process. At the moment I work exclusively with distributed memory as it seems quite difficult for me to optimize hybrid parallel codes (MPI + OpenMP for example)

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I can't broadcast the vector because it is very big (two vectors wouldn't fit on a single process), and a majority of the processes will need a tiny fraction of the vector's data to end the while loop. As I explained in my other comment, this vector stores a tree, so sometimes I only need to get the root and eventually some of the first internal nodes to know I can stop the exploration.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Actually I would have liked to remove the fence, but how can I be sure that I can safely do the final MPI_Win_free without a synchronization? From my point of view, one process X could end its while loop, and then reach MPI_Win_free while other processes would still need to read the vector of process X.

Comment: `MPI_Win_free()` is a collective operation (that must be called after `MPI_Win_unlock()`) so I do not expect any issue here.

Comment: If you only need a tiny portion of the vector, you should not worry too much about performance!

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet the size of the portion I need is unknown a priori. For some pairs of processes it will be tiny, for some other pairs it will be quite big. The performance is really linked to the ability to get data only when it's needed.